# Are promised chrome apis broken?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

The [docs](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/cookies/#method-getAll) say they showld be there but I keep getting "no matching signature" error.
What's up with this? Must I use callbacks?
Thanks

Comment: we are not aware of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the polyfill that Mozilla put together for this -- webextension-polyfill.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/webextension-polyfill

Comment: Thanks. That's perfect...in patchy way ;-)
Why would they keep such a broken documentation though?